# Windows Server 2012 - Amazon ec2 web server not able to access from outside with public ip

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed tomcat-8 on the Amazon ec2 Windows server 2012 R2 Standard(trail version).

Now I am able to access the tomcat server on the local machine with default port 80 as,

http://localhost/test

and it works with private ip

http://172.31.51.127/test

But the same is not working from outside the server with public ip.

I have tried the following,

1) In Inbound rules, opened all the ports.

2) Disabled the windows firewall.

Still no luck. Can any one guide me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Steps that worked for me:

EC2:

- In Security Group open related ports in inbound Rules. (Which u already did)
- Don't disable windows Instance Firewall.
- In Windows firewall Properties, just set Inbound Connections to **Allow** for Domain, Public and Private Firewall Profiles..

EIP:

- Check whether Elastic IP is mapped to your instance.
- Check if you can use RDP with that Elastic IP and Ping it if necessary (to

check ICMP is open).

Should work now. just make changes to Domain, Public and Private Firewall profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The default port for tomcat is 8080 (and not 80). Ensure that you have the right port open in the security groups.